# Generate a JWT in Node using inputs like jwt IO

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have a header, payload, and a public/private key. I can plug these all into JWT.io and it works as expected, but I'm struggling how to use these same variables with a node library like jsonwebtoken or other similar options. They seem to take a secret and sign a payload as far as I can see, which doesn't seem to line up with my inputs. I need to dynamically generate this token request so I must have the function in Node.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [jsonwebtoken NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken), which offers amongst other methods, a `sign` method:

```js
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('private.key');
var payload = { foo: 'bar' };
var token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
```

As @jps has pointed out, you need the private key to sign and the public key to verify.

The header will be automatically generated and will include both properties (`alg` and `typ`) you have mentioned in your comment. You can add additional properties by passing them in the `options.header` parameter.

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious, but where does my public key go, in JWT.io it accepts both public and private? Also, headers? I think that is in options, is that covered with the algorithm choice? My header is just {
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}

Comment: @edencorbin The public key is only needed to verify the signature, therefore you use it with `jwt.verify()`. For signing, you only need the private key, as shown in the answer.

Comment: This did indeed work, I was confused why you enter the public one in JWT.io.

Comment: @edencorbin you pass in the public key in JWT.io to verify that the JWT you pasted in the tool was indeed signed with the private key belonging to the public key

Answer (score 1):

> I'm struggling how to use these same variables with a node library

```js
import * as jose from 'jose';

const privateKey = await jose.importPKCS8(privateKeyPEM); // private key just like on jwt.io

const jwt = await new jose.SignJWT(payload) // payload just like on jwt.io
  .setProtectedHeader(header) // header just like on jwt.io
  .sign(privateKey);
```

Of course there's [more](https://github.com/panva/jose/tree/v4.11.2#documentation) to be [discovered](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/v4.11.2/docs/classes/jwt_sign.SignJWT.md#table-of-contents) if you need it.